# Script in InDesign to separate document into individual files with naming capabilities

Tags: adobe-indesign, indesign-scripting, javascript

I'm looking for a script that can separate a document into individual InDesign files that, upon extraction, allows for some naming capabilities for each page such as either:

- adding a suffix (page width & page height)

*or*

- using the bookmark name

*or*

- typing in an entirely custom name in a dialogue box upon running the script

For example:

If I had a single document with 5 pages, the script would split that file into 5 separate files – and upon running the script, it would have an option to split them named according to any of the naming options mentioned above.

Comment: This isn't a scripting service. Please share what you have tried and where you are having difficulty.

Answer (score 2):

InDesign does have a default way of breaking down a document on export into individual PDF docs, one per page, with some file naming options. Beyond this, you're on your own: more customization would indeed involve scripting.

[image]